# i need to update text values of step 1 data using bulkWrite method and $,$[],arrayFilters how can i do please explain

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("65bc98f235375d1d97621e06"),
  name: 'Aspirin',
  type: 'Pain Relief',
  forms: [
    {
      formType: 'TabletsData',
      strength: '100mg',
      dosageInstructions: [
        {
          time: 'Morning',
          instructions: [
            {
              step: 1,
              text: 'Take 1 tablet with breakfast.',
              _id: ObjectId("65bc98f235375d1d97621e09")
            },
            {
              step: 2,
              text: 'Drink a full glass of water.',
              _id: ObjectId("65bc98f235375d1d97621e0a")
            }
          ],
          _id: ObjectId("65bc98f235375d1d97621e08")
        },
        {
          time: 'Evening',
          instructions: [
            {
              step: 1,
              text: 'Take 1 tablet with dinner.',
              _id: ObjectId("65bc98f235375d1d97621e0c")
            },
            {
              step: 2,
              text: 'Avoid taking on an empty stomach.',
              _id: ObjectId("65bc98f235375d1d97621e0d")
            }
          ],
          _id: ObjectId("65bc98f235375d1d97621e0b")
        }
      ],
      _id: ObjectId("65bc98f235375d1d97621e07")
    },
    {
      formType: 'Capsule',
      strength: '200mg',
      dosageInstructions: [
        {
          time: 'Afternoon',
          instructions: [
            {
              step: 1,
              text: 'Take 1 capsule in the afternoon.',
              _id: ObjectId("65bc98f235375d1d97621e10")
            },
            {
              step: 2,
              text: 'Take with or after food.',
              _id: ObjectId("65bc98f235375d1d97621e11")
            }
          ],
          _id: ObjectId("65bc98f235375d1d97621e0f")
        },
        {
          time: 'Night',
          instructions: [
            {
              step: 1,
              text: 'Take 1 capsule before bedtime.',
              _id: ObjectId("65bc98f235375d1d97621e13")
            },
            {
              step: 2,
              text: 'Avoid taking with dairy products.',
              _id: ObjectId("65bc98f235375d1d97621e14")
            }
          ],
          _id: ObjectId("65bc98f235375d1d97621e12")
        }
      ],
      _id: ObjectId("65bc98f235375d1d97621e0e")
    }
  ],
  ingredients: [
    'Acetylsalicylic Acid',
    'Inactive Ingredient 1',
    'Inactive Ingredient 2'
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `updateMany` method to change the `text` value of all matching documents.

From your sample documents that match `step : 1` you have different `text` for different times of the day. I presume you don't want to update every single `text` to be the same value so here is an example that will set the `text` to `"NEW VALUE"` only when `step : 1` and `time: "Morning"`

```js
const queryStep = 1;
const queryTime = "Morning";
db.collection.updateMany({
  "forms.dosageInstructions.instructions.step": queryStep
},
{
  $set: {
    "forms.$[].dosageInstructions.$[a].instructions.$[b].text": "NEW VALUE"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "a.time": queryTime
    },
    {
      "b.step": queryStep
    }
  ]
})
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ui7asUrhj4c) for a working example of `update` on mongoplayground.

You have `__v` property which suggests mongoose. An example using mongoose would be:

```js
const queryStep = 1;
const queryTime = "Morning";
const result = await MedicineModel.updateMany({
  "forms.dosageInstructions.instructions.step": queryStep
},
{
  $set: {
    "forms.$[].dosageInstructions.$[a].instructions.$[b].text": "NEW VALUE"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "a.time": queryTime
    },
    {
      "b.step": queryStep
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also update multiple nested array object elements conditionally in multiple documents via the following update/aggregation query ( [mongoDB v.4.2+](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) ):

```
db.collection.update({ "forms.dosageInstructions.instructions.step": 1 },
[
 {
"$addFields": {
  "forms": {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$forms",
      "as": "f",
      "in": {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$f",
          {
            "dosageInstructions": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$$f.dosageInstructions",
                "as": "d",
                "in": {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                    "$$d",
                    {
                      "instructions": {
                        "$map": {
                          "input": "$$d.instructions",
                          "as": "i",
                          "in": {
                            $cond: {
                              if: {
                                $eq: [
                                  "$$i.step",
                                  1
                                ]
                              },
                              then: {
                                $mergeObjects: [
                                  "$$i",
                                  {
                                    "text": "New Value"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              else: "$$i"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
            }
           ]
         }
       }
     }
    }
   }
   ],
   {
    multi: true
   })
```

**Explanation:**

1. Match only documents having at least one step=1
2. $addFileds->$map over the 3x nested arrays  and use $mergeObjects[] changing via $cond only the nested element having step=1 with the text:"New Value"

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rVvDMKrEN6O)